# Configure diagnostic setting for azure database using Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-monitoring, azure-diagnostics, azure-sdk-python

I want to configure diagnostic setting for Azure database using Python. I know that I have to use [DiagnosticSettingsOperations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-monitor/azure.mgmt.monitor.v2017_05_01_preview.operations.diagnosticsettingsoperations?view=azure-python) Class, and [MonitorManagementClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-monitor/azure.mgmt.monitor.v2017_05_01_preview.monitormanagementclient?view=azure-python) Client, and [create_or_update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-monitor/azure.mgmt.monitor.v2017_05_01_preview.operations.diagnosticsettingsoperations?view=azure-python#create-or-update-resource-uri--name--parameters----kwargs-) method to start. I am fairly new to Python development, and I am struggling to put the pieces together.

However, there is no proper examples on what parameters to pass for the DiagnosticSettingsOperations Class.

Sample code:

```
from azure.mgmt.monitor import MonitorManagementClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

####### FUNCTION TO CREATE AZURE AUTHENTICATION USING SERVICE PRINCIPAL #######
def authenticateToAzureUsingServicePrincipal():

    # Authenticate to Azure using Service Principal credentials
    client_id = 'client_id'
    client_secret = 'client_secret'
    client_tenant_id = 'client_tenant_id'

    # Create Azure credential object
    servicePrincipalCredentialObject = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=client_tenant_id, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)

    return servicePrincipalCredentialObject


azureCredential = authenticateToAzureUsingServicePrincipal()
monitorManagerClient = MonitorManagementClient(azureCredential)
```

I want to configure Diagnostic setting for Azure sql database, which selects ALL Metrics and Logs by default and sends to a Log analytics workspace. Does anyone know how to proceed further?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. It would be really helpful. if there was a way to set ALL metrics and LOGS bydefault. This way I can have one function, that I can call to set diagnostic settings for all my resources.

Comment: I think it's impossible:(. I've already checked the [Diagnostic Settings - Create Or Update api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/diagnosticsettings/createorupdate#definitions), it does not provide a value like **all** for logs/metrics.

Comment: Is there any other way/method that I can use to get the METRICS / LOGS for an Azure resource like Microsoft.Sql.Servers. So I can get the Metrics/logs and set them to enabled.

Comment: please try `mgmt_client.diagnostic_settings_category.list(RESOURCE_URI)` as per [this link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/monitor/azure-mgmt-monitor/tests/test_cli_mgmt_monitor.py#L504), I didn't test it yet. If it's not working, please raise a new issue and let me know:)

Comment: I was able to get the metrics list of a resource by using the code: metricsObjectsList = (monitorManagerClient.diagnostic_settings.list(resource_uri)).value[0].metrics

Comment: after some testing,  unfortunately the code: 'metricsObjectsList = (monitorManagerClient.diagnostic_settings.list(resource_uri)).value[0].metrics' --> fetches values of the existing diagnostic setting (Enabled/Disabled). If no diagnostic settings is configured, it does not return anything. That is, value[0].metrics -> throws index out of bound exception.

Comment: ok, could you please raise a new issue about that, then let me know the url? I'm a little busy now, and will take a look tomorrow:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks like below:

```
 #other code

 monitorManagerClient = MonitorManagementClient(azureCredential)

 # Creates or Updates the diagnostic setting[put]
 BODY = {          
          "workspace_id": "the resource id of the log analytics workspace",
           "metrics": [
             {
               "category": "Basic",
               "enabled": True,
               "retention_policy": {
                 "enabled": False,
                 "days": "0"
               }
             }
             #other categories
          ],
          "logs": [
            {
              "category": "SQLInsights",
              "enabled": True,
              "retention_policy": {
                "enabled": False,
                "days": "0"
              }
            }
            #other categories
          ],
          # "log_analytics_destination_type": "Dedicated"
        }
 diagnostic_settings = self.mgmt_client.diagnostic_settings.create_or_update(RESOURCE_URI, INSIGHT_NAME, BODY)
```

There is an example in [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/monitor/azure-mgmt-monitor/tests/test_cli_mgmt_monitor.py#L465), you can take a look at it. And if you want to select ALL Metrics and Logs, you should add them one by one in the `metrics` / `logs` in the `BODY` in the above code.